# Ubercart: Create order with products programmatically Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, ubercart

How can i create order with products in my custom form?
This my code:

```
$order = Order::create(array(
  'uid' => $uid,
  'order_status' => uc_order_state_default('post_checkout'),
));
$order->save();
uc_order_comment_save($order->id(), $this->currentUser()->id(), $this->t('Order created by the administration.'), 'admin');
$product = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
uc_order_product_save($order->id(), $product);
```

Order was saved.... But no product related in my order. Please help!

I use drupal 8.3 and Ubercart 8.x-4.0-alpha5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also don't find why your code is not working...
But i have find a solution to relate a product to Order Id.

Try this code to assign the product to Order Id.

```
$product = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('uc_order_product')->create(array(
'qty' => 1,
'order_id' => $order->id(),
'nid' => $nid,
));

$product->save();
```

Comment: I am not able to do it programmatically in my custom form that extends FormBase class. Any classes we need to extend or use?